# How to create custom api with parameters in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, parameter

How to create custom api with multiple parameters passed in the api call file in magento1. I have added the code in request call. But it is not working.

Thanks in advance

wsdl.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <complexType name="testPushNotificationCreateArray">
          <complexContent>
              <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                  <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:testPushNotificationCreate[]"/>
              </restriction>
          </complexContent>
      </complexType>
       <complexType name="testPushNotificationCreate">
        <all>
          <element name="token" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="customer_group_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="channel" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </all>
      </complexType>
    </schema>
  </types>
  <message name="dzPushnotifTokenCreateRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="data" type="typens:testPushNotificationCreate"/>
  </message>
  <message name="dzPushnotifTokenCreateResponse">
 <!--    <part name="result" type="typens:testPushNotificationCreateArray"/> -->
    <part name="result" type="xsd:int"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
     <operation name="dzPushnotifTokenCreate">
            <documentation>TEST</documentation>
            <input message="typens:dzPushnotifTokenCreateRequest"/>
            <output message="typens:dzPushnotifTokenCreateResponse"/>
        </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="dzPushnotifTokenCreate">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded"
                           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded"
                           encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
      <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following link is a step by step link to create custom API in Magento1  with sample source code, a bit old though.

https://tutsplanet.com/magento-api-steps-create-web-service-magento-v2/

**EDIT**

You may check the below code for the input parameters.

```
<message name="productsapiActiveListRequest">
<part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="websiteId" type="xsd:string" />
```

And you can check the testcall.php included in the zip file given a link at the bottom of the tutorial. The test file shows how to call the params in the API

Comment: Thanks. I have created a custom module and it is working. But not able to pass parameters in the api call.

Comment: @user78358 Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Working fine only for single parameter. Not working for multiple parameters. Added the value inside the array. But it takes one value only. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you happen to change the type while you passing the array as parameter? <part name="websiteId" type="xsd:string" />

Comment: Yes I have changed to array parameter to type="typens:testPushNotificationCreate"